# React - Convert this.setState with callback into functional useState

Tags: reactjs, class, react-hooks

I have a class component with the method below:

```
   callBackCatAndSubcat = (values, type) => {
    if (type === 'jobs') {
      this.setState({ jobsSelected: values }, () => (
        this.props.setFieldValue('jobsSelected', _.map(this.state.jobsSelected, (item) => item.id))
      ));
    }
  };
```

and i'm converting this component into a functional component to use hooks... i'm trying to convert this method, but it isn't working

Current code:

```
  const [jobsSelected, setJobsSelected] = useState([]);
  const callBackCatAndSubcat = useCallback((items, type) => {
    if (type === 'jobs') {
      setFieldValue('jobsSelected', items.map((item) => item.id));
    }
  }, [setFieldValue]);
```

I'm not receiving an error, but the function isn't working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike class components, function components do not have a callback when you set state to tell you when the component has been updated. In most cases, I would just call `setFieldValue` on the next line, using `items` in the calculation instead of `jobsSelected` (which you are already doing). The current component will not yet have rerendered, but that's usually not a problem, since the data you need already exists in the variable `items`.

```
if (type === 'jobs') {
  setJobsSelected(items);
  setFieldValue('jobsSelected', items.map(item => item.id));
}
```

If for some reason you must wait until the current component has rerendered, and only then call setFieldValue, you can put the code in a `useEffect`, to be run after rendering:

```
const callBackCatAndSubcat = useCallback((items, type) => {
  if (type === 'jobs') {
    setJobsSelected(items);
  }
}, [setFieldValue]);

useEffect(() => {
  setFieldValue('jobsSelected', jobsSelected.map((item) => item.id))
}, [jobsSelected]);
```